# AdMob BannerAd slow to render on screen in Flutter app

Tags: admob

I have a scrolling list in a Flutter app. The list is paginated so retrieves data from the backend in batches of 10 and appends an `AdWidget` containing a `BannerAd` to the end of each batch. When scrolling, there are gaps between batches where the ads are supposed to be. Eventually the ad does appear, it just takes a long time to render. Is there anything I can do to speed up the rendering of the AdWidget?

I'm calling `load()` on the BannerAd as soon as it is added to the batch. From the logs (which can be seen in [This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Ju4vlJ6vlzQ)), it can be seen that the Future returned by `load()` completes quite quickly and the BannerAd's `onAdLoaded` and `onAdImpression` callbacks are triggered quite quickly too but, despite this, the ad still takes a lot longer to render.

[googleads-mobile-flutter issue #80](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/80) talks a lot about the performance of `AdWidget` but mainly focuses on Android, whereas I'm experiencing slow performance on iOS.

Under the hood `AdWidget` uses a UiKitView to display the BannerAd on iOS. The documentation for this states that `Embedding iOS views is an expensive operation and should be avoided when a Flutter equivalent is possible.` So I'm wondering if that is why the ad is taking so long to render...

Comment: Issue https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/875 seems to be related